# Javascript - Set default values for object optional fields in function params

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function myFunction(data, options = { merge: true, cache: false }) {
   console.log({ merge: options.merge });
   console.log({ cache: options.cache });
   console.log("----------------------");
}


myFunction({}, { cache: true });
myFunction({}, { merge: false });
myFunction({});
```

How can I do, in the above example, to avoid losing the default value of the optional field "merge"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use the fallback values feature of destructuring

```js
function myFunction(data, options = {}) {
    const {merge = true, cache = true} = options;
    console.log({merge});
    console.log({cache});
    console.log("----------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use default value assignment with the destructuring assignment notation

```
{ merge = true, cache = false } = {}
```

```js
function myFunction(data, { merge = true, cache = false } = {}) {
   console.log({ merge: merge });
   console.log({ cache: cache });
   console.log("----------------------");
}


myFunction({}, { cache: true });
myFunction({}, { merge: false });
myFunction({});
```

Comment: The main problem with this is the nomenclature (not using Typescript)

Comment: Do you want to avoid multiple declaration of `merge` and `cache`?

Comment: yeah, if possible. Anyways, I like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways:

```
function myFunction(data, options) {
  options = {merge: true, cache: true, ...options}
  console.log({merge: options.merge});
  console.log({cache: options.cache});
  console.log("----------------------");
}
```